# My statusBar no se ve en los emuladores de iPhone 11 con iOS 13

Tags: xcode, swift4

Tengo un problema, estoy trabajando con Xcode 11.3.1 y cuando ejecuto mi app, que esta app fue creada en una versión anterior de Xcode, no se ve mi statusBar, no se si es un bug de los emuladores o me hace falta alguna configuración.

Si ejecuto mi app me aparece de esta forma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo porque no se esta mostrando el statusBar, he intentado con este codigo pero no me funcioan.

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
if #available(iOS 13.0, *){
  let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
  navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
  navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
  navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
  navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standarAppearance = navBarAppearance
}
```

Pero no he conseguido mostrar la barra de estados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo tengo así:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
            navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
            navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
            navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .red
            self.navigationItem.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
            self.navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
        }
```

La diferencia con tu código son las dos últimas líneas, la asigno directamente al `self.navigationItem` y en tu código lo agregas al `self.navigationController?.navigationBar`.

Puedes intentar agregar directamente al `navigationItem` que tienes y comentando esta línea:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
```

Comment: Gracias, por tu respuesta pero el problema era otro, solamente tenia que cambiar la forma en la que el segue se presenta de un show a present modaly y poner full screen pero tu codigo me sirvio para cambiar el color de la status bar¨Muchas gracias